# Set text width - Andengine gles 2

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I have code:

```
Text infoText = new Text(560, 10, mFont, "this text is too long to be in one line",  activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

How I can set this text width(for example 200px). When text will be longer than this width it should break line and write more in next line.

I can' t find any example for this. Is it possible in Andengine gles 2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a link to the example from the AndEngine examples

https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/TextBreakExample.java

that should do it for you

Answer (score 4):

I was looking around in AndEngine's code to find a solution for your problem, and I think I've found it. The method `splitLines` in the [FontUtils](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/opengl/font/FontUtils.java) class seems to be what you need.

It's arguments are: the the text you're splitting, the font to measure widths with (The font you'll be using for the text), an object that extends `List<CharSequence>` to save the new lines in, the type of split (`AutoWrap.WORDS` to split by words) and the maximum width per line.

Comment: It' s aslo very interesing solvation. Thanks

Comment: Thanks aslo for this: AutoWrap.WORDS. I used it in connection to TextBreakExample